# Setup codeigniter URL with multiple methods within one class

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

sample url:

first url:
http://sample.com/api/campaign/999 - this url contains the next url:

http://sample.com/api/campaign/list/1

How can i setup my routing url for `campaign` as the method followed by `id`
and also has `list` method which also has an `id`

Comment: what do you mean with "this url contains the next url"?

Comment: the page contains the next url~

Comment: Is `api` the controller or is it a folder containing the `campaign` controller?

Comment: api is the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with dedicated method (assuming `Api.php` is controller file). 
Make list() method and put meant code in there

```
public function list($arg)
{
    // code for this one
}
```

Then in `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` resolve requests:

```
$route['api/campaign/list/(:num)'] = 'api/list/$1';
$route['api/campaign/(:num)'] = 'api/campaign/$1';
```

If you don't want `api/list/1` accessible, resolve it with `.htaccess` redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/api/list/(.*)$ /api/campaign/list/$1
```

Comment: thanks @Tpojka, i did what you suggested but in api/campaign/list/1 - the `list` method is not being called its still using the `campaign` method, though i can access api/list/1 which should not be the case

Comment: Changed routes file a bit. Check it now.

Comment: @woninana Have you made change in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes, .htaccess was modified, still - in campaign/list/1 - it still calling the `campaign` method hmm

Comment: Test it in private browser window. Make sure you don't rely on old browser cache.

Comment: use a different browser and still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168766/discussion-between-tpojka-and-woninana).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this that does not require any routes or `.htaccess` tricks.

```
class Api extends CI_Controller
{

    public function campaign($param1, $param2 = FALSE)
    {

        if(is_numeric($param1))
        {
            $this->do_something($param1);
        }
        elseif($param2)
        {
            $valid_methods = ['list', 'foo', 'bar'];
            if(in_array($param1, $valid_methods))
            {
                $this->$param1($param2);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function do_something($param)
    {
        echo "Doing somethig with $param";
    }

    protected function list($param)
    {
        echo "running list using $param";
    }

    protected function foo($param)
    {
        echo "running foo using $param";
    }

    protected function bar($param)
    {
        echo "running bar using $param";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i find this solution useful for my other controller. a bit handy as well for managing short controls